# Каково происхождение слов статья и кстати?

Tags: этимология

Эти слова, вероятно,  связаны с глаголами *стать, стоять*, но способ их образования, а также смысловые связи  не очень ясны.

Кроме того, интересно, когда эти слова появились в языке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все эти слова однокоренные — стать, кстати восходят к праслав. **-stati*; со *статьей* труднее.

В ЭСРЯ под ред. Шанского хорошо написано про *кстати*:

> **Кстати** (в нужный, подходящий момент, заодно с чем.-л.). Собственно
>   русское. Впервые отмечается, по-видимому, во Франд.-
>   русском словаре И. Татищева 1816 г. (I, 41) в форме с раздельным
>   написанием к стати, к делу. Возникло лексико-синтаксическим
>   способом путем слияния предлога к с формой
>   дат. п. ед. ч. сущ. стать «склад, стан» (КрЭС, 171), общеслав.
>   и.-е. характера. См. Фасмер, III, 100. См. статный, стать.

**Насчет *статьи*.** Шапошников возводит ее к английскому state, что интересно, но вот древнерусское слово *статиѥ*, которое употреблялось в значении названия отделов церковных песнопений (см. «Толковый словарь с этимолог. коммент.» Шведовой) вносит разлад в эту гипотезу о родине публицистики и журналистики. Вот скриншот статьи из материалам к словарю ДРЯ Срезневского:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысловые связи можно попробовать понять. Ну, положим, то, что написано, установлено — стать, а некое соединение, объединение этой стати — статья (м. б., семантически отдаленно похоже на фиг ~ фигня, но это совсем беглое предположение).

Забавные факты: какое-нибудь немецкое *Statt* 'место' или *Stadt* 'город' — тоже родственники *стати*. Туда же: франц. *état*, греч. *στέω* и т. д. — в общем, большое и.-е. гнездо.

Answer (score 3):

В этимологическом словаре А.К. Шапошникова есть оба слова.

> **Кстати** — нареч. вовремя, в подходящий момент; пользуясь случаем, вместе с тем; вводн. сл. в дополнение к сказанному, в связи со
>   сказанным.
>   В рус. языке XI–XVII вв. изв. **некъстати**.
>   Собств.-рус. образование, получившееся в результате слияния предлога с
>   формой дат. п. ед. ч. **къ** от «стан, склад».

(В словаре Циганенко указано, что слово **кстати** впервые фиксируется в словаре Даля. Все этимологические словари единодушны в вопросе происхождения.)

> **Статья** — научное или публицистическое сочинение небольшого размера; глава, раздел в каком-л. документе, перечне, справочнике;
>   разряд, группа (спец.); занятие, дело (устар. разг.); наказание на
>   основании закона (по статье закона; прост.).
>   Статья «глава,
>   разделяющаяся на разные стихи» отм. в словаре 1776 г.,
>   **статья** – с 1782 г.
>   При неясном посредстве из англ. state «излагать, изложить, заявить», ср. stating, statement «заявление,
>   изложение, утверждение». Англия – родина журналистики и публицистики
>   (с XVIII в.). Слово было переоформлено как сущ. на -**ья**.

(Не все словари придерживаются этой версии.)

**Дополнение.**
Просьба обратить внимание на комментарий **ain92** с полезной ссылкой.

Comment: Спасибо. Со статьёй более или менее ясно (у нас есть выражение "постановление"), получается статья - это  "то, что поставлено в книгу". А вот про кстати не очень понятно. Хотя склад и стан - это можно понимать как то, что поставлено/сказано/обозначено  ранее.

Comment: @Ксения Я понял так, что **некстати** появилось в языке намного раньше и обозначало буквально нынешнее "не к месту" (стать — место, одно из значений слова в те времена). А **кстати** уже образовалось как отрицание от **некстати.**

Comment: Да,  я тоже так поняла: сначала   - не к месту, а потом уже  - к месту.

Comment: Вообще-то слово "кстати" (с орфографическими вариантами "къ стати", "кстатѣ" и "къ статѣ"), как и его антоним "некстати" (с аналогичными вариантами), есть в Словаре XVIII века (http://feb-web.ru/feb/sl18/slov-abc), так что слово появилось до Даля.
К сожалению, до буквы С не дошёл ни этот исторический словарь, ни два других (XI-XIV и XI-XVII вв.), и значение слова "стать" быстро проверить не получилось, но я рискну предположить, что словосочетания "к стати" и "не к стати" появились примерно одновременно, и слово "стать" там использовалось в одном из своих нормальных для того времени значений.

Comment: @ain92 Спасибо за интересный и ценный комментарий! И мне странно, что слова "кстати" нет у Трубачёва (раз оно есть по Вашей ссылке).

Comment: @grizzly С чего бы Трубачёву писать о нём в ЭССЯ, если это явно поздняя великорусская инновация, отсутствующая в других славянских языках?)